# How to call people with two racial backgrounds in English?

Tags: terminology

My mother is an American and my father is a Chinese, is there a term for people with two racial backgrounds in English?

Update: Is "halfer" a good word for it? Is it kinda derogatory?

Comment: "Race" generally groups humans into a very short list of races (roughly 6, but there is disagreement). "Chinese" might be better viewed as an ethnicity or nationality. "American" is a nationality and a culture, but doesn't denote a particular ethnic or racial grouping.

Comment: Is "halfer" a good word for it? Is it kinda derogatory?

Comment: I haven't heard "halfer" before. Obviously, if you said it about yourself, people wouldn't take it as derogatory, but I would advise against saying it about other people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term I'm familiar with is 'biracial.'

Comment: I agree. "Biracial" is the general adjective for someone with parents (or, I suppose, grandparents) of two races. "Multiethnic" might also be a useful term for user4457 to know, since it moves from "race," to a more granular concept of ethnicity, and it can denote more than two ethnicities in one's family, so someone can have a Chinese, a Korean, a Polish and a French grandparent.

Comment: Great point, wordsmythe.

Comment: *Multiracial* is also used.

Comment: Is "halfer" a good word for it? Is it kinda derogatory?

Comment: That sounds pretty solidly derogatory, @user4457.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, if one of the two racial backgrounds goes back many generations (i.e., is considered to be more or less homogenous), we might self-identify as **I'm half ~~~~~~.** For instance, someone might want to describe themself as *half-Chinese* or *half-Lithuanian.* I use the latter for myself, because it is true. *Half-American* does not work, because American is not a race in this sense. But a lot of people might wish to refer to themself as (for example) *half-Irish*, *half-Greek*, *half-Italian*, *half Japanese*, *half-Cherokee*, etc. I am talking about people referring to themselves.

For someone to self-identify as *half-something* is usually a sign that they value that racial or genetic component of their background. In other words, it is a term that is used positively.

People can also refer to others as *half-something,* which may or may not be true, and may or may not be intended as a kind statement.

Cautian: We have the term [*half-breed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-breed), which also refers to someone who is considered (rightly or wrongly) to be half something. It is an offensive term, a racial slur, and pretty much no longer used in today's English. But it is encased in our popular culture, largely due to [cowboy-and-Indian movies](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls002152237/), where you might hear the term *half-breed* used to describe someone who is half-American Indian and half-something else. In the 1970s television show, [Kung Fu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_Fu_%28TV_series%29), the main character is half-Chinese and half-Caucasian American.

Answer (score 1):

Here we say *mixed ethnicity.* The term *mixed race,* although implied, would not be used officially in a multicultural society since it might offend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the term [Eurasian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Eurasian) for someone who is half Asian, half European.

Answer (score 1):

The term *dual heritage* is also used in public services to describe someone with two ethnicities.